# .toUpperCase() Button to capitalize all text in a TextArea

Tags: javascript, textarea, capitalize

What would I have to do in order to have a button present to click to convert all text in a textarea to capitalized letters?  Not just the first letter, but every letter.

Thanks much for your help

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: `toUpperCase` upper-cases every letter

Answer (score 4):

you can use css to do that use text-transform:uppercase;

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('#buttonID').click(function() {
   var upperString = $('#textAreaID').val().toUpperCase();
   $('#textAreaID').val(upperString);
});
```

Or using JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('buttonID').onclick = function() {
   var uppperString = document.getElementById('textAreaID').value.toUpperCase();
   document.getElementById('textAreaID').value = upperString;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I needed. Everything I was trying wouldn't work correctly. Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome :) If that helped you then you may proceed with accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#my_textarea").css({textTransform:"uppercase"})
```